# Regarding the Facebook pixel code to track certain events and multiple Facebook IDs on one site

Tags: facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel, facebook-pixel-helper

Regarding the Facebook pixel code to track certain events and multiple Facebook IDs on one site, im trying to learning using pixel code to run the ad

I have never previously used pixels as a Facebook advertising method, I am trying to track my ad conversion events using the pixel method but I am afraid to make a mistake in entering this code into my site, is the code that I implemented correct? If it's wrong, please help me to correct it.

the code is listed as below

```
<!-- Meta Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '*******3888');
fbq('init', '******8035');
fbq('track', 'Purchase');
<button onClick="fbq('track', 'Purchase');">Sign Up</button>
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=********3888&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=******8035&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/>
<!-- End Meta Pixel Code -->
```

because my site only have a button for registration, can I input purchase as a command to track registrations on my site